# Printing accented characters on the terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm running a Java program from command line in Ubuntu, and trying to print accented characters onto the console. But the characters get displayed as `?` on the console.

How do I make the shell display accented characters that are output from the program?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your terminal emulator is already able to display accented characters properly using a given encoding you should configure the JVM to use that encoding.

This might be the proper way:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
java yourApplication
```